# C Math assignment

Tags: c, math, variable-assignment

I have to make a program that calculates the amount of coins needed to pay for something. I.E.

```
total cost = $1.35
$1.00 = 1, remaining $0.35
$0.25 = 1, remaining $0.10
$0.10 = 1, remaining $0.0
$0.05 = 0, remaining $0.0
$0.01 = 0, remaining $0.0`
```

My question is how do I do these math operations using modulus? as part of the assignment I have to do the calculations using modulus and integer division but i can't see how using modulus would work for this code. The code I started out with is the following

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    float topay, change;
    float gst = 1.13;                               //gst amount
    int loonies, quatres, nickles, dimes, pennies;     //coin variables
    printf ("Please enter the amount to be paid: $");
    scanf ("%f", &topay);                           //Input for amount to be paid
    printf ("GST: %.2f\n", gst);
    printf ("Balance owing: $%.2f\n", topay=topay*gst); 
    loonies = topay;            //Math for amount of loonies
    change = topay - loonies;   //Math for balance owing
    quatres = change/0.25;      //Math for how many quarters needed
    printf ("Loonies required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", loonies, change);
    printf ("Quarters required: %d, balance owing $%.2f\n", quatres, change = change-(quatres*0.25));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use an int to represent the number of cents, instead of a float to represent dollars.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus tells you the remainder following a division operation.  So:

$1.35 modulus $1.00 yields 35 cents

So, you need to store 35 cents somewhere but also subtract it from the balance:

$1.35 - $0.35 = $1.00

Now you use integer division to see how many dollar coins in $1.00.  Answer is one.

Okay, now the balance is $0.35.  And the next coin is a quarter, $0.25.

So, $0.35 modulus $0.25 is $0.10.  Store the ten cents.

Subtract $0.10 from the balance gives $0.25.  How many quarters in $0.25?  Answer one.

Okay, now the balance is $0.10.

And around you go.

This can be done in a simple loop with an array holding the coin denominations.